# How to use *ngFor to filter an unknown number of elements in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular-reactive-forms, angular-forms

I need to create a search input that filters a list of sub-accounts within each parent account. Currently, typing in either input filters all accounts instead of only the associated account.

**Live Examples** (StackBlitz)
[Basic (no FormArray)](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-filter)
[With FormArray](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-form-array-filter)

**Requirements**

1. The number of accounts and sub-accounts is unknown (1...*)
2. Each account requires it's own search input (FormControl) in the HTML
3. Typing in input A should filter the list for account A only.
   Typing in input B should filter the list for account B only.

**Questions**

1. How can I ensure that each FormControl only filters the account in the current *ngFor context?
2. How can I independently watch an unknown number of FormControls for value changes? I realize I can watch the FormArray, but I'm hoping there's a better way.

Ideally, the solution should:

1. Use Reactive Forms
2. Emit an Observable when the value changes
3. Allow FormControls to be added/removed from the form dynamically

Comment: Shrink your question to the paragraph.

Comment: Unfortunately, you are unlikely to get any sold answers because you haven't included your code **in the question body**.  Links to 3rd party sites where your code might be running are not a replacement for this.

Comment: that being said, looking at your examples, you only have a single `searchTerm` property but you have multiple arrays you are trying to filter.  You will need to find a way to make each search box unique (probably using `ind` from the parent repeater), and have a unique `searchTerm` per sub-repeater.

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I'll give it a try on Monday. I decided Stackbliz would be better since it was a lot of code. I was down-voted for the question being too long, but I'll keep that in mind!

Comment: Claies led me in the right direction. I'm using the following (for now):
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-form-array-basic-solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my approach to solve your problem.

First you iterate through your outer accounts and create for every account a dedicated `formControl` and store them in a `FormGroup`. As an ID reference I used the account number. With this in place I declared a function called `getSearchCtrl(accountNumber)` to retrive the right `formControl`.

Use `[formControlName]="account.accountNumber"` to connect your template with your formControls provided in your `FormGroup`.

Reference the correct `formControl` with `getSearchCtrl(account.accountNumber)` to your `filter` `pipe` and pass the value.

`<div *ngFor="let subAccount of account.subAccounts | filter : 'accountNumber': 
      getSearchCtrl(account.accountNumber).value; let i=index">
    <span>{{subAccount.accountNumber}}</span>
</div>`

I also edited your stackblitz app: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-filter-4trpka?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

I hope this solution will help you.

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  searchForm: FormGroup;
  searchTerm = '';
  loaded = false;

  // Test Data. The real HTTP request returns one or more accounts.
  // Each account has one or more sub-accounts.
  accounts = [/* test data see stackblitz*/]

  public getSearchCtrl(accountNumber) {
    return this.searchForm.get(accountNumber)
  }

  constructor() {
    const group: any = {}
    this.accounts.forEach(a => {
      group[a.accountNumber] = new FormControl('')
    });
    this.searchForm = new FormGroup(group);
    this.loaded = true;
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.searchForm.valueChanges.subscribe(value => {
      console.log(value);
    });
  }
}
```

```html
<ng-container *ngIf="loaded; else loading">

  <div [formGroup]="searchForm">
   <div *ngFor="let account of accounts; let ind=index" class="act">
    <label for="search">Find an account...</label>
    <input id="search" [formControlName]="account.accountNumber" />
    <div *ngFor="let subAccount of account.subAccounts | filter : 'accountNumber': getSearchCtrl(account.accountNumber).value; let i=index">
     <span>{{subAccount.accountNumber}}</span>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
</ng-container>

<ng-template #loading>LOADING</ng-template>
```

Comment: This solution has a few potential problems: 
1. Since the Form is created in the constructor and does not use a FormArray, I don't think there's an easy way to add or remove FormControls dynamically without recreating the entire Form.
2. The getSearchCtrl method is called every time Angular detects a change and is called once for each account, which may effect performance.

There's probably a simpler RXJS solution, but I appreciate that the answer uses Reactive Forms and makes minimal changes to my code. It was the most helpful response to my original question.

Answer (score 1):

In the previous answer, the filter function will be called on every change detection (basically any event in the browser unrelated to this component too), which might be bad. A more Angular and performant way is to utilize the power of Observable:

```
<input #search/>
<div *ngIf="items$ | async as items">
   <div *ngFor="let item of items">{{item.name}}</div>
</div>

items:any[];
items$:Observable<any>;
@ViewChild('search') search:Elementref;
ngOnInit() {
   const searchProp = 'name';
   this.items$ = Observable.fromEvent(this.search.nativeElement, 'keyup').pipe(
      startWith(''),
      debounceTime(500), // let user type for half a sec
      distinctUntilChanged(), // don't run unless changed
      map(evt => this.items.filter(
         item => !evt.target.value || 
         item[searchProp].toLowerCase().indexOf(evt.target.value) >-1 
         )
      )
}
```

Written on tablet from memory, if it doesn't work by copy-pasting, use ide hints to look for errors. :)

This way you could even pipe the API call into the same observable, removing the need to subscribe & unsubscribe yourself, as async pipe handles all that.

Edit: to adapt this to work with 2 inputs, you can merge .fromEvent() from both, and in the filter call, change behavior according to evt.target.id. Sorry for incomplete example, writing code on tablet is horrible :D

RXJS merge: https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/merge.html

Comment: How would you implement this using Reactive Forms (so we don't lose form validation, for example)?

Comment: You can use this.myForm.get('searchControl').valueChanges which is an observable as the source of the stream instead of Observable.fromEvent().

Comment: That's what I'm currently using, but with a FormArray. I think RXJS will ultimately lead to the best solution, but your answer didn't quite get me there yet (and I need to move on). I upvoted your answer. Thank you!

Comment: Thanks! Sorry I couldn't post a complete code. Usually just on tablet when hanging here. Anyway getting comfy with rxjs will definately pay off in the long run. Dozens of hours in but hundreds out :)

Answer (score 0):

Ref [Angular.io - Pipe - Appendix: No FilterPipe or OrderByPipe](https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe)

> Angular doesn't offer such pipes because they perform poorly and prevent aggressive minification.

Based on that advice, I would replace the pipe filter with a method.

As @Claies says, you also need to store the search terms separately.
Since the number of accounts is unknown at compile time, initialize the searchTerm array  with `Array(this.accounts.length)` and handle empty searchTerms with `this.searchTerms[accountIndex] || ''`.

**app.component.ts**

```js
export class AppComponent {
  accounts = [
    {
      accountNumber: '12345',
      subAccounts: [ 
        { accountNumber: '123' },
        { accountNumber: '555' },
        { accountNumber: '123555' }
      ]
    },
    {
      accountNumber: '55555',
      subAccounts: [
        { accountNumber: '12555' },
        { accountNumber: '555' }
      ]
    }
  ];

  searchTerms = Array(this.accounts.length)

  filteredSubaccounts(accountNo, field) {
    const accountIndex = this.accounts.findIndex(account => account.accountNumber === accountNo);
    if (accountIndex === -1) {
      // throw error
    }
    const searchTerm = this.searchTerms[accountIndex] || '';    
    return this.accounts[accountIndex].subAccounts.filter(item => 
      item[field].toLowerCase().includes(searchTerm.toLowerCase()));
  }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```html
<div>
    <div *ngFor="let account of accounts; let ind=index" class="act">
        <label for="search">Find an account...</label>
        <input id="search" [(ngModel)]="searchTerms[ind]" />
        <div *ngFor="let subAccount of filteredSubaccounts(account.accountNumber, 'accountNumber'); let i=index">
            <span>{{subAccount.accountNumber}}</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Ref: [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-filter-yh5riz?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: It's trivial to write these yourself. Don't hesitate. Without seeing performance benchmarks that prove that calling a method in the viewmodel is faster than using a pipe, which is just calling a method in the view , I find the statements made in the documentation to be baseless. In fact, a pure pipe might well be faster than a method since it can be optimized by looking at the AST and determining when it does not need to be recalculated, something which is not possible with an opaque method call.

Comment: **'In fact, a pure pipe might well be faster...'** - the docs do go on to say **'...such pipes must be impure and that Angular calls impure pipes in almost every change-detection cycle'**. Having recently seen the discussion about removal of pipes from the Vue framework, I can see this discussion getting quite involved. In any case, in the absence of the benchmark you mention I'd be inclined to follow the documentation.

Comment: Interesting about Vue. Regarding purity, that's definitely not true because I've written a pure pipe that filters an array that does exactly what I want. It doesn't modify the input array, it simply returns a new array.

Comment: It is literally `@Pipe({name: 'filter'}) class F {transform = (xs, p) => xs.filter(x => p (x))}`

Comment: Anyway, the designers of the Aurelia framework have a very different view on the matter, and they've written about it publicly. I would suggest that as a point of comparison. Because Aurelia runs as fast as Angular. The reason I don't buy into the documentation is because of when it was written. It was written during a holy war between AngularJS and React about two-way data binding. It turned out that holy war was a stupid war... which is of course true of all Holy Wars

Comment: Yes, I'd have to agree with you about the filter pipe being pure. In which case, it functions pretty much the same as a method.

Comment: At the end of the day, I think I ***would*** use a pipe, particularly if there was potential to re-use it on more than one component.

Comment: Thanks Richard! This solution has a few potential problems:
1. It assumes a fixed number of accounts and doesn't use Reactive Forms, so I don't think there's an easy way to add or remove FormControls dynamically.
2. The filter method is called every time Angular detects a change and is called once for each account, which may effect performance.

I upvoted your answer and it works for the simplified example I gave, but I ultimately used a solution closer to SplitterAlex's suggestion.

Comment: @AluanHaddad, I recently saw a further explanation about pure filter pipes (or rather pipes when used with an array), they don't respond to changes to the input array. To make them do so requires the `pure: false` attribute, but then they will respond to all change cycle updates, which is where the performance hit comes in. I note that the requirement for handling account array changes was not overtly given in the question, but later commentary seems to have introduced it.

Comment: @RichardMatsen great point. I don't like to code in that style (i.e. I would write `add(x) { this.xs = [...this.xs, x]; }` where a pure pipe is optimal) so it slipped my mind. I would like to remove my downvote but can not.

Comment: In terms of recalculation of the filter expression when a non-related update occurs (e.g add an timed counter to the view), ***only*** the pure pipe does not recalculate for every view change. The filter method and the Rx based solution both do so.

Comment: This is a really hard problem actually. Since array constituency can change without affecting the length, it implies either explicit checking or dirty checking.

Comment: @AluanHaddad - no worries about the downvote, calls attention to the somewhat obscure documentation.

Comment: This is a good answer though and you did implement a pipe anyway. I'll note that angular will need to reevaluate the expression `filteredSubaccounts(expr)` if it cannot determine how `expr` is derived. By the way, if you use `changeDetectionStrateg.onPush` you it means that rebinding the array will be required and a pure pipe sufficient.

Comment: @AluanHaddad - **This is a really hard problem actually** indeed. I spent some time looking for the Angular feature that equates to Vue's computed property (which I believe would do this job since it caches results and watches it's own dependencies).

Comment: **rebinding the array** and a pure pipe - yes that sounds like the optimal way.

Comment: @RichardMatsen I will read up on them in Vue. Aurelia and EmberJS have decorators `@computedFrom('otherPropertyName')` that enable fast watching without dirty checking. Unfortunately, arrays, objects, maps, and sets require different approaches.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to create an account component to encapsulate each account and it's search. There would be no need for a pipe in this case -  [Example app](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-filter-oxn7sn?file=app%2Faccount.component.ts)

```js
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-account',
  template: `
    <label for="search">Find an account...</label>
    <input id="search" [(ngModel)]="searchTerm" />
    <div *ngFor="let subAccount of subAccounts()">
      <span>{{subAccount.accountNumber}}</span>
    </div>
    <br/>
  `
})
export class AccountComponent {

  @Input() account;
  @Input() field;
  private searchTerm = '';

  subAccounts () {
    return this.account.subAccounts
      .filter(item => item[this.field].toLowerCase()
        .includes(this.searchTerm.toLowerCase())
    ); 
  }
}
```

The parent would be

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <div>
      <div>
        <app-account *ngFor="let account of accounts;"
          class="act" 
          [account]="account" 
          [field]="'accountNumber'">
        </app-account>
      </div>
    </div>
  `,
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  accounts = [
    ...
  ];
}
```